# Function Returning Excel COM Objects Unexpectedly

Tags: excel, powershell, com

```
function xlAssignRange
{
    Param($shtSheet, [string]$strRange)

    $rngRange = $shtSheet.Range($strRange)

    $rngRange
    return
}
```

When I use the above function to assign an Excel COM object for a range of cells, the behavior is a bit unexpected in that this returned object is handled similar to a `ForEach-Object` instead of a "whole" object.

As an example:

```
$rngA1E10 = xlAssignRange $shtSheetOne "A1:E10"
```

The above code puts range `A1:E10` into `$rngA1E10`, but if I do the following:

```
$rngA1E10.Select()
```

Each of the cells is **individually selected, one at a time, ending on E10.**  This is not what I expected or intended to happen.

What I actually expected to happen is the functionally working equivalent here, not using the function above:

```
$shtSheetOne.Range("A1:E10").Select()
```

The above selects/highlights the **entire range** of `A1` through `E10`, which is my intended behavior.

How do I fix the way that this function returns the variable so that it is handled "as a whole object," as opposed to iterating through each component of said object?

EDIT: As strictly just *another example,* of the same unintended behavior:

```
function xlCopyRange
{
    Param($strRange)

    $strRange.Copy() | Out-Null
}
```

Passing `xlCopyRange` a range of `"E1:E10"` would only result in the clipboard having the value of E10 after it is completed (I can see the "True" for each value as it iterates through each of the individual cells in the Range by omitting `Out-Null`).

Please note that these are just examples of ranges being used in functions, but not being acted on **as a whole**, but rather iterating through each of the cells within said range passed to a function.

Comment: Personally, I don't see why you want to create a function for something you can do in one short and simple command.. Anyway, try with a function that only has `$shtSheet.Range($strRange)` and remove the rest except for the parameters. Now your function outputs both `$rngRange` followed by a `$null` because of the return

Comment: @Theo - Fair point, but for what it's worth, I provided this as an "example," but have run into this with several other functions that return an object that is actually an array (or handle an array previously returned before being acted upon within the new function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return an array as a single object, you have two solutions according to [about_Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return):

1. You can use the unary array expression:

   ```
   function xlAssignRange
   {
       Param($shtSheet, [string]$strRange)

       $rngRange = $shtSheet.Range($strRange)

       return (, $rngRange)
   }
   ```
2. Or you can use `Write-Output` with the `-NoEnumerate` parameter:

   ```
   function xlAssignRange
   {
       Param($shtSheet, [string]$strRange)

       $rngRange = $shtSheet.Range($strRange)

       return Write-Output -NoEnumerate $rngRange
   }
   ```

Casting `$rngRange` to an array will also work in your case:

```
function xlAssignRange
{
    Param($shtSheet, [string]$strRange)

    [array] $rngRange = $shtSheet.Range($strRange)
    
    return $rngRange
}
```